# report page setup problem?

Tags: rdlc

```
select * from ........
```

this query out put are

```
sn   id  name    fatherName

1     1    A     Asssss

2     2    B     ABssss

3     3    C     ABCsss

4     4    D     ABCDss
```

show **RDLC** report on basis of SN .Each SN print on each page. After print on row information rest of page must be blank......

like :

> page 1

`1     1    A     Asssss`

rest of page blank

> page 2

```
2     2    B     ABssss`
```

all are same as.....i have four **SN** so i must get the four page and each page just have one row information........which property or which condition help me to do?

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  Put a page break after every row.